# Probability that I choose the $k+3$th candidate after rejecting first $k$ candidates

Tags: probability

Suppose my strategy is to reject first $k$ candidates in an interview, and then choose the first future candidate who is better than all of my first $k$ rejections.

There are $N$ candidates in total. Now, assuming the $k+1$th candidate is the absolute best out of the group, he gets picked with probability 1 using this strategy.

Assuming the $k+2$th candidate is the absolute best, he gets picked only if the $k+1$th candidate is rejected. The $k+1$th candidate gets accepted with probability $\frac{1}{k+1}$. So he gets rejected with probability $1-\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{k}{k+1}$. So, the probability that the $k+2$th candidate gets picked assuming he is the absolute best is $\frac{k}{k+1}$

**My question**

What is the probability that the $k+3$th candidate gets selected assuming he is the absolute best?

The $k+3$ candidate gets selected only if both $k+1$ and $k+2$ get rejected.

So this probability = 1-P(selecting $k+1$ or $k+2$)

P(selecting $k+1$ or $k+2$)=P(selecting $k+1$)+P(selecting $k+2$)-P(selecting $k+1$ and $k+2$)

The last term is 0 as both can't be selected

Since $k+1$ is selected only if he is the best out of the group $(1,2,3.....k+1)$,

P(selecting $k+1$)=$\frac{1}{k+1}$

Since $k+2$ is selected only if $k+1$ is rejected and $k+2$ is the best out of the group $(1,2,3,...,k-1,k,k+2)$,

P(selecting $k+2$)=$(1-\frac{1}{k+1})\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}$

So P(selecting $k+1$ or $k+2$)=$\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{2k+1}{(k+1)^2}$

So P(selecting $k+3$)=$1-\frac{2k+1}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2}$

However, the correct answer is supposed to be $\frac{k}{k+2}$. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Candidates $k+1$ and $k+2$ get rejected iif the best of the first $k+2$ candidates is one of the first $k$ candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel Mathias in the comments points out an easy argument to get the correct answer. Let me include it for completeness, since comments may be transient:

> Candidates $k+1$ and $k+2$ get rejected iff the best of the first $k+2$ candidates is one of the first $k$ candidates.

Now by symmetry this answer is obviously $\frac{k}{k+2}$.

However, your question is where you went wrong. The step in your answer that is false is this one:

> Since $k+2$ is selected only if $k+1$ is rejected and $k+2$ is the best out of the group $(1,2,3,...,k−1,k,k+2)$, $$P(\text{selecting } k+2)=(1−\frac1{k+1})\cdot\frac1{k+1}=\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}.$$

You compute these probabilities separate, but that only works if the events "$k+1$ is rejected" and "$k+2$ is the best out of the group $(1,2,3,...,k−1,k,k+2)$" are independent. In fact these are not independent events: if $k+1$ is rejected, that suggests that the first $k$ candidates were more likely to be stronger, which means $k+2$ is also more likely to get rejected.